PDF FO.NET special characters on windows not working
If I have the following XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Value01>≥</Value01>
    <Value02>&#x2265;</Value02>
</Data>

and then generate a PDF on linux using apache fop the "greater than equal to" symbol appears fine from both forms. But when I try to generate on windows with FO.NET I get a "#" appearing instead.
Is there a way around this?

What is FO.NET exactly, how old is it, how do you configure it to find its fonts? Using a current version of IKVM you should be able to integrate the latest Apache FOP version in .NET framework or .NET core code and perhaps achieve better results.

FO.NET is available via nuget and is pretty good, but does seem to be based on possibly an early version of Apache FOP or just does not implement all of it. Had a quick look at FOP.NetCore which makes use of IVKM but it appears there is no source for it just dll's in it's nuget package so it will be a non starter without source. Unfortunately I'm maintaining an existing suite which relies on FO.NET so it may take a lot to re-engineer. Plus think I found answer to my original issue / question

So this works in part
<fo:inline font-family="Symbol">&#x2265;</fo:inline>

The only issue is I need to refactor either the data and or code to split it out from the the other items that need to use a non Symbol font family at the block level. Curiously Apache FOP on linux appears to automatically know to use the Symbol font for this and no <fo:line is needed as can be found by looking at fonts used in the resulting pdf. Whereas FO.NET does not use Symbol unless explicitly told to, seemingly.
